# I need help creating a script to find error logs in Docker

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I'm trying to create a bash script that can find error logs from a docker container. Essentially we will have an ID like ABC1234567 and I am I'm trying to create a script in Bash that asks for the ID and tells you which container has the error of the case. The code I have so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash

#ask for case ID
echo 'Enter Case ID'
read caseID

#run container check
docker logs con1 2>&1 | grep -B 4 $caseID
docker logs con2 2>&1 | grep -B 4 $caseID
docker logs con3 2>&1 | grep -B 4 $caseID
docker logs con4 2>&1 | grep -B 4 $caseID
docker logs con5 2>&1 | grep -B 4 $caseID
docker logs con6 2>&1 | grep -B 4 $caseID
```

Now, this does work, because once the ID is found in one of the containers, it does throw back a bunch of dialogue about that container, including the case ID, but it's mostly useless info and really it's just an indicator that we found the right container. The problem is that it doesn't tell me which container had the case ID. What would I need to add so that it can echo the Container name back at us? For example if I run the code I am expecting it to just say something like
`Error in Con3`

I tried to make an ifelse statements but I don't necessarily know the argument I am looking for. If it helps the output that comes out when the error ID is found in one of the containers actually contains that ID as a casename. This is my first time actually working with Docker so I am a bit limited in my knowledge for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility might be to refactor your script to utilize a loop and output the current container name.

```
#!/bin/bash

#ask for case ID
echo 'Enter Case ID'
read -r caseID

for i in 1 2 3 4 5 6 ; do 
    echo "checking con$i"
    docker logs "con$i" 2>&1 | grep -B 4 "$caseID"
done
```

Comment: Thank you! I think this was the answer I was looking for because it does work. The new, less worrisome problem is that it runs 6 times now. The problem is that I used 'con' as an example, the actual identifiers are something like a7e or bb2, things like that. But you've given me more then enough to tackle the job. Thank you!